# How do I make an animated border that goes around a window and the border at end disappears? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface

I want an animated border that goes around a window, so in a window. I want it to make it look like something is moving around the window like in this [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqb0kaRdyyA).

I have found some codes online and I modified it to go around a window, but it doesn't go transparent, just look at the video; and you'll know what I am talking about, the code is also kinda hard to understand and a mess. I'm really new to C# so please help me out thanks.

The border of each side is split it into columns, Col1 is the left side and Col2 is the right side, and the numerical values are the time which it starts animating.

```c#
    private void InitSbs()
    {
         topEdgeSb = CreateSb("TopEdgeCol1", "TopEdgeCol2", "TopEdge", true, 0);
         rightEdgeSb = CreateSb("RightEdgeCol1", "RightEdgeCol2", "RightEdge", false, 500);
         bottomEdgeSb = CreateSb("BottomEdgeCol1", "BottomEdgeCol2", "BottomEdge", true, 500 * 2);
         leftEdgeSb = CreateSb("LeftEdgeCol1", "LeftEdgeCol2", "LeftEdge", false, 500 * 3);
    }
```

```
        private GridLengthAnimation CreateGridLengthAnim(string name, double from, double to, bool isCol,  int beginTime, int duration)
        {
            GridLengthAnimation anim = new GridLengthAnimation();
            anim.From = new GridLength(from, GridUnitType.Star);
            anim.To = new GridLength(to, GridUnitType.Star);
            anim.Duration = new Duration(new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, duration));
            anim.BeginTime = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, beginTime);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, name);
            if (isCol)
            {
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty));
            }
            else
            {
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(RowDefinition.HeightProperty));
            }

            return anim;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            topEdgeSb.Begin(this, true);
            leftEdgeSb.Begin(this, true);
            bottomEdgeSb.Begin(this, true);
            rightEdgeSb.Begin(this, true);
        }
```

Some problems in this code is that I've specified the edgeDuration, which specifies how long it takes for a border to go from start to finish. edgeDuration is 500 ms and the resetTime is
500 ms + beginTime. So let's say that I want to animate the bottom-most border, that is third border that will be animated which then is going 500 ms + 500 * 3, we multiply 500 by 3 because that how long it takes to animate the borders that will be animated before the bottom-most border.

However despite this, the animation in the left border ( 4th order ) stops before even fully animating like around 95%.

Comment: You would use a path animation to move your object along a path that reflects the boundaries of the window. Note that you can't render outside the client area of a window. This means the animation will actually be inside the window and not outside the window (like a decorator). To achieve the decorating look you would have to override the window chrome to add padding around the new window caption/title bar and border.

Comment: [Path Animations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-animations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. A Path Animation could also work and perhaps be a little cleaner and more flexible, but this seemed like a straightforward way to illustrate a potential solution.

```xml
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowAnswers.Wpf.AnimatedBorder"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowAnswers.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AnimatedBorder"
        Height="200"
        Width="200"
        BorderThickness="0"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        x:Name="Window">
    
    <Border Padding="3">

        <Border Background="#333333"
                CornerRadius="5"
                MouseDown="AnimatedBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Border Margin="-3,-3,3,3"
                    x:Name="Grid">
                <Ellipse Name="MyRectangle"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Width="6"
                         Height="6">
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform"
                                            X="0"
                                            Y="0" />
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush"
                                         Color="Gold" />
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                    <Ellipse.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                                     From="0"
                                                     To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                                     From="0"
                                                     To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Grid}"
                                                     BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                                     To="0"
                                                     From="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}"
                                                     BeginTime="0:0:1"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                                     From="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Grid}"
                                                     To="0"
                                                     BeginTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Ellipse.Triggers>
                </Ellipse>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Border>

</Window>
```

```cs
    public partial class AnimatedBorder : Window
    {
        public AnimatedBorder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void AnimatedBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MouseDevice.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                DragMove();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image: Result]